# Git is not tracking changes to a .rdb redis db file?

Tags: git, redis

I am experimenting, a lot of my application is controlled by what is inside the `.rdb` file, like configuration and content.

So I thought I would setup a repo on my server and set the `.rdb` file inside the repo `redis-cli` then `CONFIG SET dir /path/to/repo/.rdb`.

Then data changes as users add content and admins update settings.
Ideally I can pull this into my local branch and have the updates and everything is consistent with the server.

What I am struggling with is, Git does not seem to recognize there is a change.   I add some content then do a `git status` on my repo with no changes detected.

Am I missing something? Is it possible and is it practical to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am struggling with is, Git does not seem to recognize there is a change
>     Am I missing something?
>     Is it possible and is it practical to do something like this?

Looks like you have a `.gitignore` file which setup to ignore your `.rdb` files.

Edit the file and remove the extension from there so your files will be tracked.

**If you are unix check the `/etc/redis/redis-<version>/.gitignore` and you will see it in there.**

---

If they are not there check to see if you have set the `--assume-unchanged` on this file.

## ***`--assume-unchanged`***

```
# tell git not to track local changes made to this file
git update-index --assume-unchanged <path>
```

In case you need to print out list of files marked with the `--assume-unchanged` flag:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

Comment: This is essentially the .gitignore https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/blob/master/.gitignore I dont see any reference to .rdb. In my project I have it stored in `data/dump.rdb`

Comment: Which os? if you are on Unix/Mac there can be a `.gitignore` on the system level and not project level. (assuming you are on macc: since there is a **.DS_Store** entry)

Comment: There can be one under you home and one more under the system git folder in MAC

Comment: Its on my server which is running linux

Comment: Check all your ignore files. `sudo updatedb`, `locate .gitignore` and view all of the results

Comment: Why do you have  .DS_Store if you are UNIX?

Comment: Because I am working locally on Mac os x but I have a repo on my server that I also point my redis CONFIG to so I can just pull locally. Also the .DS_Store is ignored because if a developer is on a mac it wont push to the remote

Comment: You have this entry in one of your .gitignore files for sure

Comment: You are right `/etc/redis/redis-2.8.19/.gitignore` would this directory effect it?

Comment: Yep, remove the entry form the file and you will see it.